# How to draw 3D object

Tags: 3d

Is here anyone who can help me with this object? I don´t even know where to start :( Thank you for answers.

[image: 3D-object]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) As it is currently written, this question falls into the "do-it-for-me" category, which is not well received on this website. In order to receive help, you have to provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/184389) showing what you have already tried and what abstract issue you are struggling with. To get you started, you could search this very website for examples related to your query or go to the [TikZ documentation](https://tikz.dev/).

Comment: You can start with the triangle in the middle and use polar coordinates, such as `\draw (90:1) -- (210:1) -- (330:1) -- cycle;` then, step by step, draw the rest.

Comment: What is your figure about? Could you provide its context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!

Another one, this one a 3d solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,perspective}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={240}{15},scale=2,line cap=round,line join=round]
% coordinates
\foreach\i in {0,...,5}
  \coordinate (A\i) at (60*\i:1);
\foreach\i in {0,1,2}
{
  \coordinate (B\i) at ($(120*\i+30:{sqrt(1/3)})+(0,0, {sqrt(2/3)})$);
  \coordinate (C\i) at ($(120*\i+90:{sqrt(1/3)})+(0,0,{-sqrt(2/3)})$);
}
% back
\draw[gray] (A4) -- (A5) -- (A0) -- (A1);
\draw[gray] (C0) -- (C2) -- (A0) -- (B0) (C1) -- (C2) -- (A5) -- (B2);
% inner
\draw[orange] (A0) -- (A3) (A1) -- (A4) (A2) -- (A5) (B0) -- (C1) (B1) -- (C2) (B2) -- (C0);
% front
\draw (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- (A4);
\draw (B0) -- (B1) -- (B2) -- cycle;
\draw (A1) -- (B0) (A2) -- (B1) -- (A3) (A4) -- (B2);
\draw (A1) -- (C0) -- (A2) (A3) -- (C1) -- (A4) (C0) -- (C1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, if you change the view:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={220}{15},...
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, using polar coordinates, drawing this is quite simple at least if you want to keep the perspective like this (which would then not require any 3D-related libraries):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% outer cooridinates
\coordinate (A) at ([shift={(90:1)}]30:1);
\coordinate (B) at ([shift={(150:1)}]90:1);
\coordinate (C) at ([shift={(210:1)}]150:1);
\coordinate (D) at ([shift={(270:1)}]210:1);
\coordinate (E) at ([shift={(330:1)}]270:1);
\coordinate (F) at ([shift={(30:1)}]330:1);

% inner coordinates
\coordinate (a) at (30:1);
\coordinate (b) at (90:1);
\coordinate (c) at (150:1);
\coordinate (d) at (210:1);
\coordinate (e) at (270:1);
\coordinate (f) at (330:1);

\draw[gray] 
    (a) -- (c) -- (e) -- cycle
    (a) -- (A) -- (B) -- 
    (c) -- (C) -- (D) -- 
    (e) -- (E) -- (F) -- cycle;

\draw[red!50] 
    (A) -- (D)
    (B) -- (E)
    (C) -- (F)
    (a) -- (d)
    (b) -- (e)
    (c) -- (f);

\draw 
    (b) -- (d) -- (f) -- cycle
    (b) -- (B) -- (C) -- 
    (d) -- (D) -- (E) -- 
    (f) -- (F) -- (A) -- cycle;

\draw[thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- (F) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]